# Использование Sinatra AssetPack в админке Padrino

Tags: ruby, sass

Использую для проекта фреймворк [`Padrino`](http://www.padrinorb.com/) (v 0.10.7), основанный на `Sinatra`. Для поддержки `CoffeScript` и `Sass+Compass` решил воспользоваться пакетом [`Sinatra AssetPack`](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack). При этом в папках с приложениями, я создал специальную папку assets для скриптов, т.е. `app/assets/stylesheets` и `admin/assets/stylesheets`. Все сделал как описано в руководстве и на фронте все отлично работает. Но когда я пытаюсь сделать то же самое для админского приложения, то получаю 404-ю ошибку.

Настройка `assets` в админском приложении:

```
class Admin < Padrino::Application
  # ...
  register Sinatra::AssetPack
  register Sinatra::CompassSupport

  # configure AssetPack
  assets {

    serve '/admin/stylesheets',   from: 'assets/stylesheets'       # Optional
    serve '/admin/images',        from: 'assets/images'            # Optional

    css :app, '/admin/stylesheets/app.css', [
       '/admin/stylesheets/*'
    ]

    css_compression :sass       # Optional
  }

  # ...

end
```

При открытии админки возникает ошибка:  `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myawesomesite.loc/admin/stylesheets/application.217646.css"`

Нужен совет по решению данной проблемы. Как настроить assetpack?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ С ОТВЕТОМ:**

Сайт пока не дает отвечать на свои вопросы, поэтому приведу решение здесь, вдруг кому-то пригодится. Ответ удалось получить вместе с разработчиками padrino.

Проблема заключается в особенности обработки "монтированных" приложений. Т.к. приложение `admin` подключено к пути "`/admin`", то эта "приставка" отбрасывается при дальнейшей обработке. Т.е. вместо запроса "`/admin/stylesheets/application.217646.css`" ищется "`/stylesheets/application.217646.css`", которого нет. Для эксперимента, если попытаться запросить файл добавив дополнительный префикс "`/admin`", то файл отдается нормально :)

Решить данную проблему можно перекрытием пары методов в `Sinatra::AssetPack::Package`, примерно так:

```
class Sinatra::AssetPack::Package
  # для production окружения  
  def production_path
    app_root = Padrino.mounted_apps.find{ |app| app.name == @assets.app.name }.uri_root
    asset_path = add_cache_buster( @path, *files )
    app_root == '/' ? asset_path : ( app_root + asset_path )
  end

  # для development окружения
  def to_development_html(options={})
    app_root = Padrino.mounted_apps.find{ |app| app.name == @assets.app.name }.uri_root
    path_prefix = app_root == '/' ? '' : app_root
    paths_and_files.map { |path, file|
        path = add_cache_buster(path_prefix + path, file)  # app.css => app.829378.css
        link_tag(path, options)
    }.join("\n")
  end

end
```

Может не самое красивое решение, но оно работает :) Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь!

Comment: Что тут еще может быть непонятного?  404 - Файла не существует по указанному `http://myawesomesite.loc/admin/stylesheets/application.217646.css`

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно дело в этом:

```
/admin/stylesheets/**app**.css
/admin/stylesheets/**application**.217646.css
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Если второй параметр в css, то он лишь означает в какой файл будут компилироваться все файлы из массива в третьем параметре. Т.е. он возьмет все sass файлы из папки stylesheets, скомпилирует в файл app.css и отдаст клиенту. Так это работает в prod-окружении. Т.к. я работаю в dev, то сервер отдает эти файлы по отдельности. Сам факт того, что появляется ссылка говорит о том, что assetpack находит sass файл в указанной директории. Но сервер при получении запроса не может его отдать.

Comment: Я думал ошиблись с именем файла.
А по поводу решения: разве нельзя дополнить админский класс вашим основным?

Comment: Под основным вы имеете ввиду frontend-приложение? Они равноправны, оба наследуются от Padrino::Application. Только монтируются на разные пути, фронт - на "/", а админка на "/admin". Проблема возникла из-за каких-то особенностей маршрутизации padrino, я сам до конца не разобрался в этом. Но суть в том, что assetpack при формировании ссылки на компилированный файл начинал путь без учета префикса. Решение как-раз и состоит в том, чтобы дополнить методы формирования ссылки проверкой на "монтированность" и, при необходимости, добавлением префикса.